# Amazon cognito not giving refresh token provided by federated identity provider (Google login)

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I am trying to add a Google login through Amazon Cognito, I have setup everything needed, I have also configured the attribute mapping from google to my pool attributes, I've mapped 'access_token' attribute to 'google_access_token' attribute and 'refresh_token' to 'google_refresh_token'. When sign in process starts, google prompts me for required permissions needed and redirects back to my app, and I can see on cognito dashboard that user is added with access token mapped in 'google_access_token' but no refresh token there. I double checked every configuration everything seems fine. I also tried mapping other attributes like 'token_type' and 'expires_in' those are getting mapped except the refresh token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that for generating refresh token from google, client need to pass 'access_type=offline' parameter in the GET parameters which Amazon Cognito DOESNOT send while starting OAUTH login with google, so google doesnt provide google refresh token. So in nutshell there is no way ( Atleast now ) to get refresh token from google and access google APIs "offline" if you are using Amazon cognito. Alternatively I used Auth0 which supports this and can send access_type parameter to google and can store refresh token.

Answer (score 3):

If I may ask, have you seen this document?

[Understanding Amazon Cognito user ool oauth 2.0 grants](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/)
To get to the point, this concern may be because of the  OAuth Flow we have set in the Cognito User Pool. We need to use "Authorization Code Grant" as the OAuth flow. Implicit Grant doesn't generate refresh tokens, but Authorization Code Grant does.

If you're using Amplify framework in your project, this framework will do most of the heavy lifting for you. You just need to setup the User Pool's app client correctly and configure Amplify for that specific app client.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I need to get an access token and refresh token to access Google APIs on my server. I am using grant type as Authorization Code but the tokens I am getting on my FE are generated by Cognito and not from google that's why when I am trying to access Google API I am getting 401 error. Can you please help me how can I figure this out?